# Using ChemDrawControl16 in VBA to Extract SMILES from drawn Molecule

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2016 I opend the VBA Windos (ALT + F11). Unter tools -> references I marked "CS ChemDraw Control 16.0 Library" and "CS ChemDraw 16.0 Object Library" and left with a click on "OK".
Then I created a new UserForm and a new UserForm appeared. I right clicked on the Toolbox -> Additional Controls and chose "CS ChemDraw Control 16.0".

So I created a UserForm with a ChemDraw Control Element on it and also a ControlButton. I started the UserForm and I am able to draw a structure on the ChemDraw Control Element.

What I want to know now is:
I want to extract the SMILES code of the Structure and paste it into an empty cell when I click on the Controlbutton. How do I have to code this?

My UserForm look like this:
[UserForm2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxXqT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sheets("SMILES").Range("A1").Value = Me.ChemDrawCtl1.Data("chemical/x-smiles")
```

http://www.cambridgesoft.com/services/documentation/sdk/chemdraw/ActiveX11/ChemDrawControl10~ChemDrawCtl~Data.html